# Trigger ACTION_MOVE in Fragment while finger is already pressed down

Tags: android, android-fragments, ontouch

**Setup**

In Fragment A I have a Button with an onTouchListener. If I touch the Button, Fragment A is replaced by Fragment B.

Fragment B has an onTouchListener on its root view, and I want to capture the ACTION_MOVE right away.

**What I want to achieve**
I want to be able to touch the button, see Fragment B appear and immediately act upon the touches.

**The problem**

No onTouches are called before I lift my finger and touch again.

**What I tried**

```
private void dispatchTouch(FrameLayout layout_for_dragging) {
        // Obtain MotionEvent object
        long downTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        long eventTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() + 100;
        float x = 0.0f;
        float y = 0.0f;
        // List of meta states found here:     developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html#getMetaState()
        int metaState = 0;
        MotionEvent motionEvent = MotionEvent.obtain(
                downTime,
                eventTime,
                MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN,
                x,
                y,
                metaState
        );

        // Dispatch touch event to view
        layout_for_dragging.dispatchTouchEvent(motionEvent);
    }
```

and call this in onCreateView after I set the onTouchListener to the root view.

I wanted to force an event in the hopes that it would pick up my move events, but it only calls ACTION_DOWN once.

Answer (score 0):

to handle the fragment B move to the right , you can use onPageScrolled override method 
..........
if i got your question

```
 @Override
public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {
    if(lastPage>arg0)
      {//User Move to left}
    else(lastPage<arg0) 
     {//User Move to right}
      lastPage=arg0
}

OR 


 @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

                    if (thresholdOffset > positionOffset) {
                        Log.i(C.TAG, "going left");
                    } else {
                        Log.i(C.TAG, "going right");
                    }


            }
```